# What does a matrix of dummy variables look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am reading a book, and he has this model set up.  Just focusing on matrix D, what would that matrix look like?  Would it just be a diagonal matrix of dummy variables?
[image]

Comment: It depends what that $\Phi$ means

Comment: That should just be a coefficient matrix I think.  The author doesn't really expand on that term.